# Handling missing configuration in dependency in Gradle build

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle build which produces the main deliverable artifact (an installer) of my product. The Gradle project which models this has a number of different dependencies in different configurations. Many of those dependencies are on the default configuration of external modules, and some of those modules have a `testResults` configuration that contains the (zipped) results of the test task.

It's important that those test results for all dependencies, where they exist, be published as artifacts of the main product build (to use as evidence that testing took place and was successful). It's not an issue if they don't exist.

I tried to do this by iterating over all configurations of the product build, iterating over the dependencies in each and adding a programmatically created dependency (in a new configuration created for this purpose) on the `testResults` configuration of the module.

In other words, I create dependencies like this:

```
def processDependencyForTests( Dependency dependency ) {

    def testResultsDependency = [
      'group' : dependency.group,
      'name' : dependency.name,
      'version' : dependency.version,
      'configuration' : 'testResults'
      ]

    project.dependencies.add 'allTestResults', testResultsDependency
```

This populates that configuration just fine, but of course when I try to do anything with it, it fails the first time I encounter a dependency on a module that doesn't actually **have** a `testResults` configuration:

```
   def resolvedConfiguration = configurations.allTestResults.resolvedConfiguration
```

Results in this:

```
Build file 'C:\myproduct\build.gradle' line: 353

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myproduct:createBuildRecord'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myproduct:allTestResults'.
   > Module version group:mygroup, module:myproduct, version:1.2.3.4, configuration:allTestResults declares a dependency on configuration 'testResults' which is not declared in the module descriptor for group:mygroup, module:mymodule, version:1.0
```

It's not really practical to instead explicitly list the dependencies in a declarative fashion, because I want them to be derived from "whatever **real** dependencies the product project has".

How can I ensure that such expected missing configurations don't derail my build? I thought something to do with lenient configurations might be the answer, but I haven't even got that far here (I need to get a `ResolvedConfiguration` first, as far as I can tell). Alternatively, if the way I'm doing this is insane, what's a more natural Gradle idiom to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for handling missing configurations?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to check for the existence of the configuration before referencing it. In cases like this, the [gradle DSL documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) is your friend. In fact, the gradle project is one of the most well-documented open source projects I've ever worked with.

Here, you'll find that `configurations` is simply a container of `configuration` objects. They are instances of [ConfigurationContainer](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ConfigurationContainer.html) and [Configuration](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) respectively. Knowing this, all you need to do is to check whether the `configurations` container contains a `configuration` named "testResults".

This can be achieved by the following code:

```
if (configurations.find { it.name == 'testResults' }) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: The question is about configurations in the module descriptors of artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

It seems implied that `Dependency` instances passed to your `processDependencyForTests` method are module dependencies in a multi-modules build.

In this case you could cast them to [ProjectDependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ProjectDependency.html) which has a `dependencyProject` property that will allow you to reach the `Project` object of that dependency. From there you can use `depProject.configurations.findByName` to test if the configuration exists.

Something along the lines of:

```
def processDependencyForTests( Dependency dependency ) {
  if( dependency instanceof ProjectDependency ) {
    ProjectDependency projDep = (ProjectDependency) dependency
    if( projDep.dependencyProject.configurations.findByName( 'testResults' ) ) {
      def testResultsDependency = [
        'group' : dependency.group,
        'name' : dependency.name,
        'version' : dependency.version,
        'configuration' : 'testResults'
      ]
      project.dependencies.add 'allTestResults', testResultsDependency
    }
  }
```

HTH